# Появляются сильные ссылки на объект в лямбде или слушателе, после чего GC не может очистить память

Tags: java, javafx, сборщик-мусора, listener

Есть игра на JavaFX. И я уже несколько дней пытаюсь бороться с это проблемой. Все мои сильные ссылки на объекты я удалил и не могу их найти уже на протяжении 5 дней, так что думаю проблема не у меня. Кода очень много, поэтому буду вставлять по чуть-чуть.

Есть экземпляр объекта Game в главном классе.

```
public class Main extends Application {

private static Game game;

@Override
public void start(Stage mainStage) throws Exception{
    mainStage = new Stage();
    game  = new Game();
    mainStage.setScene(game.scene);//Ставлю сцену на Stage из game
    mainStage.show();
    }
}
```

В классе Game есть поля `Scene scene` и `Fighting fighting` и вот такие методы и конструктор

```
public Game(){
    OnStart();/*Просто подгружает инфу из файлов и заполняет 
статические коллекции всякими объектами с характеристиками(Оружие)*/
    setMainMenu();
    scene.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
        keys = event.getText();
        if (event.getCode()==KeyCode.ENTER) setFighting();
        if (event.getCode()==KeyCode.ESCAPE) setMainMenu();
    });
}

public void setMainMenu(){
    if (scene == null)
        scene = new Scene(createMainMenu());
    else
        scene.setRoot(createMainMenu());
    if(fighting != null) {
        //Наверняка удаляю ссылку на объект Knight
        //getFighting() возвращает Pane fighting 
        fighting.getFighting().getChildren().clear();
        fighting = null;
        System.gc();//Безуспешная попытка бороться с GC
    }
}

public void setFighting() {
    fighting = new Fighting();
    //Этот метод возвращает Pane с картинкой(типо загрузка началась)
    scene.setRoot(fighting.createLoading());
    /*Этот костыль нужен, чтобы поток JavaFX отвлёкся от выполнения 
этого метода и картинка, показывающая, что загрузка началась 
появлялась на экране, иначе на экране остаётся главное меню и потом 
сразу появляется боевая сцена*/
    new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        Platform.runLater(() -> fighting.createPane());
    }).start();
}
```

Класс Fighting. Вся игра проходит в `Pane fighting`

```
public class Fighting {
    public ArrayList<Rectangle> collisions = new ArrayList<>();

    Pane fighting = new Pane();
    Pane loading = new Pane();
    //Те самые объекты на которые где-то появляется ссылка и GC не может их удалить
    public Knight player, enemy;
    //С этим тоже самое, но не всегда
    public FightingUI fightingUI;

    private ImageView[] bg = new ImageView[3];
    private ImageView[] bgShadow = new ImageView[3];

public Pane createLoading(){
    loading.setPrefSize(1920, 1080);
    loading.getChildren().add(bg[1]);
    if (bgShadow[1] != null)
        loading.getChildren().add(bgShadow[1]);
    return loading;
}

public void createPane() {
    fighting.setPrefSize(1920, 1080);
    //Читает инфу из файла и returns экземпляр в методе read()
    KnightReader kr = new KnightReader();
    player = kr.read("resources/Save/player.sm", false);
    enemy = kr.read("resources/Save/enemy00" /*+ league[0] + 
league[1]*/ + ".sm", true);

    collisions.add(player.collision);
    collisions.add(enemy.collision);

    //Интерфейс(UI)
    fightingUI = new FightingUI(player, enemy);
    //Просто ставит расположение "камеры"
    updateLayout();

    fighting.getChildren().addAll(enemy, player, fightingUI);
    Main.getGame().scene.setRoot(fighting);

    loading = null;
}
}
```

`Knight extends Pane`. И в Knight создаётся около 15 объектов Animation, которые не удаляются из-за наличия ссылки на них в Knight. На каждую анимация есть как отдельная ссылка, так и ссылки в коллекции. Пробовал делать метод destroy() и обнулять все сслыки на Animation, несмотря на жизнь объекта Knight, но они и тогда не удаляются тоже.

Теперь Animation. Оно работает, по такому принципу, что загружаются картинки - элементы анимации через объекты AnimElement. Тобишь есть красный шлем и синий сапог, и их можно удобно комбинировать в зависимости от экипировки игрока.

!!!Все AnimElement удаляются из памяти, скорее всего с содержащимися картинками. В профайлере объектов AnimElement не видно и без них это всё ЖРЁТ 500 мб, а с ними 730 мб(если я не обнуляю коллекцию)!!!

Так же в `AnimElement` есть `static HashMap<String, AnimElement>`. Сейчас этот кэш не используется

```
public class Animation extends Pane{

ArrayList<AnimElement> allAnimElems = new ArrayList<>();
public ImageView allFrames = new ImageView();

boolean play = false, endAnim = false, puddle = false;
public int currFrame = 0;
private boolean alignmentRight, takingDamage = false;
public final int frameCount, delay;
double width, height;
public String pathToDir;
ArmorList[] armor_id;
WeaponList weapon_id;
BodyColor[] bodyColor;
String[] elemList = new String[]{"ArmB", "OversleevesB", "", "Body", 
"Hair", "", "Eyes", "Eyebrows", "Mouth", "Ears", "Nose",
        "BootsB", "PantsB", "BootsF", "PantsF", "Cuirass", "Helmet", 
"PantsFC", "ArmF", "OversleevesF"};

//Only for taking damage animations
private AttackType attackType = null;
private int weaponId, life;

//Поток в котором анимация работает(Переставляет ViewPort на картинке)
Thread thread;

//Основной конструктор
public Animation(String pathToDir, double width, double height, int 
frameCount, int delay, ArmorList[] armor_id, WeaponList weapon_id, 
BodyColor[] bodyColor, boolean alignmentRight) {
    this.frameCount = frameCount;
    this.delay = delay;
    this.pathToDir = pathToDir;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.armor_id = armor_id;
    this.weapon_id = weapon_id;
    this.bodyColor = bodyColor;
    this.alignmentRight = alignmentRight;
    FillAllFrames();
    this.setPrefSize(this.width, this.height);
}

//Специальный простой конструктор
public Animation(String pathToDir, double width, double height, int 
frameCount, int delay, boolean alignmentRight,
                 String nameOfBlood) {
    this.frameCount = frameCount;
    this.delay = delay;
    this.pathToDir = pathToDir;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.alignmentRight = alignmentRight;
    takingDamage = true;
    AnimElement animElement;
    if (AnimElement.allElems.containsKey(pathToDir + "/" + nameOfBlood))
        animElement = new AnimElement(AnimElement.allElems.get(pathToDir + "/" + nameOfBlood), frameCount);
    else
        animElement = new AnimElement(pathToDir, nameOfBlood, false, frameCount, false);
    allFrames = new ImageView(animElement.getImage());
    animElement.destroy();
    if (alignmentRight)
        mirrorAnim();
    allFrames = ImageTools.changeSizeBy2(allFrames.getImage());
    this.width *= 2;
    this.height *= 2;
    setAlignment();
    this.getChildren().add(allFrames);
    this.setPrefSize(this.width, this.height);
}

public void play(){
    play = true;
    endAnim = false;
    thread = new Thread(() -> {
        while(play) Update();
    });
    thread.start();
}

public boolean isPlay() {
    return play;
}

public void endAnim() {
    currFrame = 0;
    setAlignment();
    if(takingDamage)
        Platform.runLater(() -> Puddle.addPuddle(attackType, weaponId, 2));
    endAnim = false;
    play = false;
    if(thread != null)
        thread.interrupt();
    thread = null;
}

public void endAnimRequest(){
    endAnim = true;
}

public void FillAllFrames(){
    //Создаёт экземпляры AnimElement и добавляет их в коллекцию allAnimElems
    AddAllElems();
    //Объединяет все элементы в одну картинку
    allFrames.setImage(ImageTools.mergeImages(allAnimElems));
    //Рабочее удаление AnimElement
    allAnimElems.clear();
    allAnimElems = null;
    //Если надо отражает картинку
    if (alignmentRight)
        mirrorAnim();
    //Увеличивает картинку в 2 раза
    allFrames = ImageTools.changeSizeBy2(allFrames.getImage());
    width *= 2;
    height *= 2;
    setAlignment();
    this.getChildren().add(allFrames);
}
private void AddAllElems(){
    setElemList();
    for (int i = 0; i < elemList.length; i++) {
        if (elemList[i].isEmpty())
            continue;

        if (checkFile("resources/" + pathToDir + "/" + elemList[i] + 
".png")) {
            if (AnimElement.allElems.containsKey(pathToDir + "/" + 
elemList[i]))
                allAnimElems.add(new 
AnimElement(AnimElement.allElems.get(pathToDir + "/" + elemList[i]),
                        frameCount));
            else
                allAnimElems.add(new AnimElement(pathToDir, 
elemList[i], false, frameCount, false));
        }else {
            if (AnimElement.allElems.containsKey("Animations/Knight/" 
+ elemList[i]))
                allAnimElems.add(new 
AnimElement(AnimElement.allElems.get("Animations/Knight/" + 
elemList[i]),
                        frameCount));
            else
                allAnimElems.add(new AnimElement("Animations/Knight", 
elemList[i], true, frameCount,
                        true));
        }
    }

}
private void setElemList(){
    //Меняет значение String elemList[]. Нужно для загрузки изображений
}

private boolean checkFile(String path) {
    return new File(path).exists();
}

private void setAlignment(){
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        if (alignmentRight)
            allFrames.setViewport(new Rectangle2D(width * (frameCount 
- 1), 0, width, height));
        else
            allFrames.setViewport(new Rectangle2D(0, 0, width, 
height));
    });
}

public void Update() {
    if (endAnim) {
        endAnim();
    }
    if (play) {
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            if (alignmentRight)
                allFrames.setViewport(new Rectangle2D(width * 
(frameCount - (currFrame+1)), 0, width, height));
            else
                allFrames.setViewport(new Rectangle2D(width * 
currFrame, 0, width, height));
        });
        currFrame++;
    }
    if (currFrame > frameCount - 1) {
        endAnim();
    }
    try {
        Thread.sleep(delay);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        endAnim();
    }
}

public void mirrorAnim(){
    allFrames = ImageTools.MirrorImageView(allFrames.getImage());
}

//Не помогает
public void destroy(){
    allFrames = null;
}
}
```

И теперь класс `AnimElement`

```
public class AnimElement {

private String pathToDir, name;
private Image allFrames;
public ArmorItems armorItemNumber;
public WeaponList weaponList;
public BodyItems bodyItemNumber;

int frameCount;
boolean isStatic = false;
public boolean relocate = false, diffRelocate = false;
//Не используется
static Map<String, AnimElement> allElems = new WeakHashMap<>();

public boolean isStatic() {
    return isStatic;
}

public int getFrameCount() {
    return frameCount;
}

public AnimElement(String pathToDir, String name, boolean isStatic, 
int frameCount, boolean relocate) {
    this.isStatic = isStatic;
    this.frameCount = frameCount;
    this.pathToDir = pathToDir;
    this.name = name;
    this.relocate = relocate;

    //Это чёрная магия и вам это по идее не нужно
    checkRelocatableItems(name.substring(0, name.length()-1));
    boolean attackDir = pathToDir.split("/")[1].equals("Attack") ||
            pathToDir.split("/")[1].equals("Block");
    boolean lowAttackDir = false;
    if (pathToDir.split("/").length > 2)
        lowAttackDir = pathToDir.split("/")[2].substring(0, 
3).equals("Low");

    if (attackDir && armorItemNumber != null && ((!lowAttackDir && 
armorItemNumber == ArmorItems.Cuirass) ||
            armorItemNumber == ArmorItems.OversleevesF || 
armorItemNumber == ArmorItems.OversleevesB))
        this.diffRelocate = true;
    else if (attackDir && bodyItemNumber != null && (bodyItemNumber == 
BodyItems.ArmF ||
            bodyItemNumber == BodyItems.ArmB))
        this.diffRelocate = true;

    allFrames = new Image(pathToDir + "/" + name + ".png");
    //Game.fightingFastLoading == false. Этот кэш не используется
    if (Game.fightingFastLoading)
        allElems.put(pathToDir + "/" + name, this);
}

//Это  конструктор как и кэш не используются
public AnimElement(AnimElement animElement, int frameCount) {
    this.isStatic = animElement.isStatic;
    this.frameCount = frameCount;
    allFrames = animElement.allFrames;
    this.pathToDir = animElement.pathToDir;
    this.name = animElement.name;
    this.relocate = animElement.relocate;
    this.armorItemNumber = animElement.armorItemNumber;
    this.weaponList = animElement.weaponList;
    this.bodyItemNumber = animElement.bodyItemNumber;
}

private void checkRelocatableItems(String name){
    try {
        armorItemNumber = ArmorItems.valueOf(name);
    }catch (IllegalArgumentException ex){}
    try {
        weaponList = WeaponList.valueOf(name);
    }catch (IllegalArgumentException ex){}
    try {
        bodyItemNumber = BodyItems.valueOf(name);
    }catch (IllegalArgumentException ex){}
}

public Image getImage(){
    return allFrames;
}

}
```

Я думаю методы из ImageTools не нужны там просто Canvas, с которого потом берётся snapshot. И полей в классе нет, все методы static и все ссылки только локальные.

Теперь, что мне удалось раздобыть из профайлера.
Если я захожу на боевую сцену и потом выхожу ничего не трогая и ни на что не наводя(На панели снизу на слотах, стоят onMouseEntered() и Exited()), то 97% памяти unrecheable from GC roots  или не имеют сильных ссылок. Они чистятся сразу, несмотря на System.gc, но они чистятся из профайлера. Вот что в дампе. Можно увидеть, что и экземпляры Knight не имеют сильных ссылок
[image]

Но если я нажимаю просто на экран(по сути на Pane fighting)(на сцене нет setOnMouseClicked) или нажимаю или навожу на слот на нижней панели, то уже после выхода в главное меню 2% памяти не имеют сильных ссылок. Вот что есть в merged paths в профайлере
[image]

Ну и вот здесь вставлю все лямбда-слушатели

```
public Slot(){
    this.setOnMouseEntered(event -> toggleActive());
    this.setOnMouseExited(event -> toggleActive());

    this.setPrefSize(128, 128);
    imageActive.setVisible(false);
    this.getChildren().addAll(imageDefault, imageActive);
}

public static Slot getActionSlot(int i) {
    Slot slot = new Slot();
    switch (i){
        case 0:
            slot.setOnMouseClicked(event -> 
Main.getGame().fighting.getAttacker().attack(AttackType.HIGH));
            break;
        case 1:
            slot.setOnMouseClicked(event -> 
Main.getGame().fighting.getAttacker().attack(AttackType.MIDDLE));
            break;
        case 2:
            slot.setOnMouseClicked(event -> 
Main.getGame().fighting.getAttacker().attack(AttackType.LOW));
            break;
        case 3:
            slot.setOnMouseClicked(event -> 
Main.getGame().fighting.getAttacker().move(true));
            break;
        case 4:
            slot.setOnMouseClicked(event -> 
Main.getGame().fighting.getAttacker().move(false));
            break;
        case 5:
            slot.setOnMouseClicked(event -> 
Main.getGame().fighting.getAttacker().sleep());
            break;
    }
    return slot;
}

private void toggleActive(){
    if(imageDefault.isVisible()){
        imageDefault.setVisible(false);
        imageActive.setVisible(true);
    }else {
        imageDefault.setVisible(true);
        imageActive.setVisible(false);
    }
}





Rectangle eventHandler = new Rectangle(64, 64);

eventHandler.setOnMouseEntered((event -> {
        description.setVisible(true);
    }));

    eventHandler.setOnMouseExited((event -> {
        description.setVisible(false);
    }));

eventHandler.setOnMouseEntered((event -> 
description.setVisible(true)));

    eventHandler.setOnMouseExited((event -> 
description.setVisible(false)));





public class PotionSlot extends Slot{

ImageView potion;
Label numberLabel = new Label();
int number;

public PotionSlot(PotionList potionList, int lvl) {

    number = getNumber(lvl, potionList);

    if(number > 0)
        potion = new ImageView("Interface/Potions/" + 
potionList.toString() + "Lvl" + lvl + ".png");
    else
        potion = new ImageView("Interface/Potions/EmptyLvl" + lvl + 
 ".png");
    numberLabel.setFont(new Font(Game.font.getFamily(), 24));

 numberLabel.setTextFill(Paint.valueOf(String.valueOf(Color.BLACK)));
    numberLabel.relocate(90, 95);
    numberLabel.setText(String.valueOf(number));
    numberLabel.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
    numberLabel.setPrefSize(30, 30);

    this.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
        if(number > 0) 
Main.getGame().fighting.player.usePotion(potionList, lvl);
    });

    this.getChildren().addAll(potion, numberLabel);
}

private int getNumber(int lvl, PotionList potionList){
    if(lvl == 1)
        return MoneyManager.potionsLvl1[potionList.ordinal()];
    else if(lvl == 2)
        return MoneyManager.potionsLvl2[potionList.ordinal()];
    else
        return MoneyManager.potionsLvl3[potionList.ordinal()];
}

public static PotionSlot getPotionSlot(PotionList potionList, int lvl) 
{
    return new PotionSlot(potionList, lvl);
}

}




public void exitPotionMenu(){
    potions[0] = new PotionMenuSlot(PotionList.Heal);
    potions[1] = new PotionMenuSlot(PotionList.Energy);
    potions[2] = new PotionMenuSlot(PotionList.Concentration);
    potions[3] = new PotionMenuSlot(PotionList.Strength);
    setPotionSlots();
}

public void goToPotionMenu(PotionList potionList){
    potions[0] = PotionSlot.getPotionSlot(potionList, 1);
    potions[1] = PotionSlot.getPotionSlot(potionList, 2);
    potions[2] = PotionSlot.getPotionSlot(potionList, 3);
    potions[3] = new ExitPotionMenuButton();
    potions[3].setOnMouseClicked(event -> exitPotionMenu());
    setPotionSlots();
}

private void setPotionSlots(){
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            i++;j++;
            potions[count].setTranslateX(807 + (j*4) + (j*128 - 128));
            potions[count].setTranslateY(4 + (i*4) + (i*128 - 128));
            i--;j--;
            count++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        this.getChildren().set(potionIndexes[i], potions[i]);
    }
}




public class PotionMenuSlot extends Slot{

ImageView potion;

public PotionMenuSlot(PotionList potionList) {

    int number = 0;
    number += MoneyManager.potionsLvl1[potionList.ordinal()];
    number += MoneyManager.potionsLvl2[potionList.ordinal()];
    number += MoneyManager.potionsLvl3[potionList.ordinal()];

    if(number > 0)
        potion = new ImageView("Interface/Potions/" +  
potionList.toString()  + "Lvl1.png");
    else
        potion = new ImageView("Interface/Potions/EmptyLvl1.png");

this.setOnMouseClicked(event -> Main.getGame().fighting.fightingUI.bottomPanel.goToPotionMenu(potionList));

    this.getChildren().add(potion);
}
}

public void goToPotionMenu(PotionList potionList){
    potions[0] = PotionSlot.getPotionSlot(potionList, 1);
    potions[1] = PotionSlot.getPotionSlot(potionList, 2);
    potions[2] = PotionSlot.getPotionSlot(potionList, 3);
    potions[3] = new ExitPotionMenuButton();
    potions[3].setOnMouseClicked(event -> exitPotionMenu());
    setPotionSlots();
}

private void setPotionSlots(){
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            i++;j++;
            potions[count].setTranslateX(807 + (j*4) + (j*128 - 128));
            potions[count].setTranslateY(4 + (i*4) + (i*128 - 128));
            i--;j--;
            count++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        this.getChildren().set(potionIndexes[i], potions[i]);
    }
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста, я уже не знаю, что делать

Comment: вы прикалываетесь? кто в этом разбираться-то будет? и что такое `сильные ссылки`

Comment: Сильные ссылки - это `Object obj = new Object()`. obj - это сильная ссылка на экземпляр объекта Object и GC не удалит объект, до тех пор пока `obj != null` . Я уже неделю пытаюсь решить эту проблему и пока ничего. Я уже не знаю, что можно сделать, поэтому написал на форум. Хз может кто-то и поможет. В любом случае мне это хуже не сделает

Comment: Вы бы попытались локализировать проблему.  Выяснить точно в каком месте что-то идет не так и только тогда давать код на осмотр. В 99% случаев при составлении короткого вопроса ответ находится сам. Проверено. Тысячу раз уже думал, что ответ сам не найду, но написав понятный вопрос он тут же находился

Comment: @SerhiiDikobrazko у меня не получается её локализировать. Всё тесты, что я пробовал ничего не дают, но я продолжу(просто уже нет идей что можно проверить). Может вы что-то сможете сказать/предположить по второй картинке?

Comment: а проблема в чем, падает с `OutOfMemoryException`?

Comment: Нет. Проблема в том, что каждый раз когда я создаю новый `Pane` и загружаю в него много `Image` через свои объекты заполняется 500 мб памяти. После `pane = null` в моём коде, моих ссылок на все эти объекты нет, но GC не может их удалить и говорит что ссылки есть. Мне кажется ссылки на них создаются где-то в коде JavaFX. Из за этого память не освобождается(а создавать новый `Pane` нужно часто) приложением становится невозможно пользоваться. А так по сути за один запуск всё нормально. Никаких бешенный заполнений памяти до `OutOfMemoryException` нет. Просто память не чистится

Comment: @dimagor555 ну так оно и не удалится, если просто присвоить null. Вы добавляеете this.getChildren().add(allFrames), тем самым создавая еще одну ссылку на сцене. По необходимости ее надо удалить вызвав  this.getChildren().removeAll(allFrames), и т.д. во всем необходимых моментах

Comment: @Serhii разве children не должны удаляться когда объект удаляется? Это странно. Но проблема в том, что я делал pane.getChildren().clear() И pane.getChildren().removeAll(объекты) и делал на каждом уровне метод destroy(), в котором тоже это всё делал и это не дало результатов. Всё равно всё объекты остались в памяти. Сейчас я нашёл, что ссылки на эти Image  начинаются из какого-то gtkView, потом цепочка идёт в NGImageView и уже там есть прямая ссылка на Image. Не удаляется главный объект и не удаляются ImgaView. Я пробовал их обнулить но это не дало результатов

Comment: @dimagor555 тогда маловероятно что кто-то сможет помочь. Если уж создателю в коде сложно разобраться, то другим и подавно. Слишком многа букав

Comment: @Serhii я уже понял, что никто не поможет. Мне в коде легко разобраться. И я знаю что моих ссылок в коде нет. Они все равны `null`. (Это уже инфа из профайлера) На всё эти объекты нет ссылок связанных с моими классами или даже объектами, которые я использую(Я использую javafx.scene.ImageView и javafx.scene.Image, а ссылки на объекты находятся в каких-то com.sun.javafx.prism.Image и ...prism.NGImageView(возможно ошибся с пакетами чуть чуть)). Это уже код JavaFX, и пока что мои действия(В т.ч. ваши советы) мне не помогли. Так что хз. У меня такого ещё не было

Comment: Вопрос можно закрывать